# Estimating the maximum throughput of an ASP.Net Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, performance-testing

I've written 2 different ASP.Net Web Forms applications that are both hosted on the same server. One of these has 3 instances (same code, different configuration accessible on a different port number). So there is a total of 4 sites running.

The code itself is relatively straightforward. There is a form, the user fills it in and submits. It logs that data to a SQL Express database, running on the same server. There are 4 different databases, one of each site, hosted on the same SQLExpress instance.

All 4 sites use SSL.

Our customer has asked me to estimate the maximum number of requests that the server could fulfil each day. I have the specification of the server but I just don't know where to begin to calculate this.

I expect I'm going to get a answer at least an order of magnitude higher than their requirements so I'm not after a really accurate number.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Bench](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm) provides a good starting point for doing load tests. With large enough request number you can get pretty good estimate of median number of requests per second.